# Facebook campaign name inside android app from sdk

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I use Facebook app install for campaigns (Bid fo mobile install type). Is there a way to get the campaign/ad name of Facebook app install from inside the app?

During campaign creation Facebook campaign panel for "mobile install" cat every additional parameters to google play (like referrer) and mantain only detail?id=appid.

Right now I didn't find a way to track campaign name myself inside the app to meauser good user aquired from google play compared to not good users.

Any solution?

Thanks

Tobia